# NDSolve for Complex Algebraic-Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

Let consider the following *complex* equations:
$$
\frac{i x(s)}{2\pi} - \frac{\log(1+ e^{-y(s)}) - \log(1 + e^{y(s)})}{\dot x(s)}
$$
which I will cal `eq1` and 
$$
\frac{2 \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{-y(s)}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{y(s)}\right)-\frac{3
   \pi ^2}{2}\right) x''(s)}{x'(s)^3}-\frac{y'(s) \log \left(e^{-y(s)}+1\right)-y'(s) \log
   \left(e^{y(s)}+1\right)}{x'(s)^2}+\frac{i y(s)}{2 \pi }
$$
which I will call `eq2`. (btw, notice that since we are in the complex domain I didn't use on purpose sum/subraction formula for polylogs, since in principle I do not know in which branch I'm in) 
More specifically

```
eq1 = -((I*x[s])/(2*Pi)) - (2*(Log[1 - E^(-y[s])] - Log[1 + E^y[s]]))/Derivative[1][x][s]
eq2 = -((I*y[s])/(2*Pi)) + (2*(-Log[1 - E^(-y[s])] + Log[1 + E^y[s]])*Derivative[1][y][s])/Derivative[1][x][s]^2 + (4*(-(Pi^2/3) + PolyLog[2,E^(-y[s])] +PolyLog[2, -E^y[s]])*Derivative[2][x][s])/Derivative[1][x][s]^3
```

I would like to solve numerically them in the interval $s\in (-1/2,1/2)$ with some initial condition, say $x(0)=0$, $y(0)=0$ and $\dot x(0) = 1$. I try to input them in

```
NDSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {s, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

I get the following warnings:

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.
NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

I think that the first warns me about the method it will use to try to solve the equations, and the second and the third tell me that in order to use IDA method I have to use real valued functions. In order to deal with this I defined

```
eq1r = (eq1 /. {x -> (xr[#] + I xi[#] &), y -> (yr[#] + I yi[#] &)}) //Re // ComplexExpand;
eq1i = (eq1 /. {x -> (xr[#] + I xi[#] &), y -> (yr[#] + I yi[#] &)}) //Im // ComplexExpand;
eq2r = (eq2 /. {x -> (xr[#] + I xi[#] &), y -> (yr[#] + I yi[#] &)}) //Re // ComplexExpand;
eq2i = (eq2 /. {x -> (xr[#] + I xi[#] &), y -> (yr[#] + I yi[#] &)}) //Im // ComplexExpand;
```

and then, when I try to execute

```
NDSolveValue[{eq1r == 0, eq1i == 0, eq2r == 0, eq2i == 0, xr[0] == 0, xi[0] == 0, yr[0] == 0, yi[0] == 0, xr'[0] == 1, xi'[0] == 0}, {xr, xi, yr, yi}, {s, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

apart for the usual warning I get some other messages like

```
NDSolveValue::nrnum1: The function value 2. -3.10849*10^-8 I is not a real number when the arguments are {-1.95313*10^-7,-7.51414*10^-33+0. I,3.84724*10^-26+0. I,-1.95313*10^-7+0. I,1. +0. I,3.10849*10^-8+0. I,-1.19591*10^-33+0. I,1,1}.
```

which I really cannot understand since I explicitly use `Re` and `Im`. I think that maybe I have been too naive.

### QUESTION

Do you have any suggestion to numerically solve these equations with Mathematica?

Comment: Add code for `eq1,eq2`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev. I added the code.

Comment: This is a misprint `PolyLog[2,E^-Y[s]]`? Should it be `PolyLog[2,E^-y[s]]`?

Comment: Your code for `eq1`, `eq2` does not work: it needs to be posted it in `InputForm`. See [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) for help. Also you have both `y` and `Y` -- You might try differentiating the algebraic equation.

Comment: Sorry for the misprint. I edited the code for `eq1` and `eq2`

Comment: The initial data `y[0] = 0` lead to the calculation of 1/0.

Comment: I do not get such an error

Comment: `NDSolve[{D[eq1 == 0, s], eq2 == 0, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
  x'[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {s, -1/2, 1/2}]` yields the error 1/0.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Maybe you take the code before the last edit

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I have pasted directly the Input Form in my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation can be solved with respect to `y[s]`

```
Solve[eq1 == 0, y[s]]
(*{{y[s] -> 
   Log[1/2 (-1 + E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) - Sqrt[
       1 - 6 E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + E^((
        I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(2 \[Pi]))])]}, {y[s] -> 
   Log[1/2 (-1 + E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + Sqrt[
       1 - 6 E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + E^((
        I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(2 \[Pi]))])]}}*)
```

We define two equations on two branches

```
eq3 = eq2 /. {y[s] -> 
    Log[1/2 (-1 + E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) - Sqrt[
        1 - 6 E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + E^((
         I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(2 \[Pi]))])], 
   y'[s] -> 
    D[Log[1/2 (-1 + E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) - Sqrt[
         1 - 6 E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + E^((
          I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(2 \[Pi]))]), s]]};
eq4 = eq2 /. {y[s] -> 
    Log[1/2 (-1 + E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + Sqrt[
        1 - 6 E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + E^((
         I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(2 \[Pi]))])], 
   y'[s] -> 
    D[Log[1/2 (-1 + E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + Sqrt[
         1 - 6 E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + E^((
          I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(2 \[Pi]))]), s]]};
```

We exclude the point `s = 0` from the solution. We solve the equations `eq,e4` on the segments `{s,-1/2,-x0}, {s,x0,1/2}`, where `x0 =10^-10`. For example

```
x0 = 10^-10; X2 = 
 NDSolve[{eq3 == 0, x[x0] == 0 + I 0, x'[x0] == 1 + I 0}, 
  x, {s, x0, 1/2}]

{Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[x[s] /. X2]], {s, x0, 1/2}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[
   ReIm[Log[
      1/2 (-1 + E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + Sqrt[
         1 - 6 E^((I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(4 \[Pi])) + E^((
          I x[s] Derivative[1][x][s])/(2 \[Pi]))])]] /. X2], {s, x0, 
   1/2}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]